# Edit distances algorithm (Levenshtein Distance) with character has different lengths?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I am working on an algorithm question, which is a modified version of Levenshtein Distance (minimum edit distance).

Now provided the strings both with an array of character lengths, and return the distance computed.

- Delete a character with length n will cost n distance, so as insert a character.
- A substitution can be treated as a deletion with an insertion cost 2n distance.
- You can partially delete a character or insert a character at arbitrary length.

Examples:

> ex1.
>   string1 = "egg" with length [1, 1, 1]
>   string2 = "eg" with length [1, 1.5]
>
> They have a distance of 0.5 (insert a 'g' with 0.5 length at the end of string2)
>
> ex2.
>   string1 = "elicit" with length [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>   string2 = "illicit" with length [0.9, 1.2, 1, 0.9, 0.9, 1.1]
>
> They have a distance of 1.9 + 0.2 + 1 + 0 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 = 3.4

An approximate solution is try to up sample the character to equal lengths and the question will have a dynamic programming solution using the Wagner–Fischer algorithm to solve it in O(n^2). However, since we sampled it, it will become an approximate solution with quantization error.

I tried to come up with a recursive version like below but it's very very slow. I tried to use hash to save the calculated value to cut branch for the recursive but it seems still pretty bad.

The recursive version in Python:

```
def lev(a, a_lens, b, b_lens):
    if not a:
        return sum(b_lens)
    elif not b:
        return sum(a_lens)
    else:
        if a_lens[0] < b_lens[0]:
            _b_lens = b_lens[:]
            _b_lens[0] -= a_lens[0]
            if a[0] == b[0]:
                change = lev(a[1:], a_lens[1:], b, _b_lens)
            else:
                change = MAX
        else:
            _a_lens = a_lens[:]
            _a_lens[0] -= b_lens[0]
            if a[0] == b[0]:
                change = lev(a, _a_lens, b[1:], b_lens[1:])
            else:
                change = MAX
        insert = b_lens[0] + lev(a, a_lens, b[1:], b_lens[1:])
        delete = a_lens[0] + lev(a[1:], a_lens[1:], b, b_lens)
        minimum = min(change, insert, delete)
        return minimum
```

How can this be improved? Is it possible for O(n^2) implementation? Any language is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: why the DP algorithm is approximation? I thought it is the exact solution when I learnt it

Comment: Some hints: (1) Suppose we have an optimal solution.  Notice that in any interval (u, v) containing purely inserted material in one side, there are no insertions in the other side (since if there were, there would be some subinterval (p >= u, q <= v) that contains inserted material on both sides, and the insertions on both sides in this subinterval could be removed to produce a lower-cost alignment, contradicting the optimality we assumed).

Comment: (2) Notice that any insertion of length x in one of the strings can be changed into a deletion of length x in the other side, to produce a different solution of the same cost.  Since this holds for *any* solution, we can apply it repeatedly to any optimal solution we have until it contains no more insertions: the resulting solution will have the same (i.e., optimal) cost.  This means it suffices to consider *only* solutions in which we delete intervals (possibly from both sides).

Comment: (3) Subdividing a character into several copies of the same character whose lengths sum to the original character's length (and also, joining several adjacent identical characters together into a single character whose length is the sum of their original lengths) does not change the cost of solving the problem.  So one way to simplify the problem is to find every "breakpoint" (x position where one character ends and the next one begins) in *either* string, and break *both* strings at each of these points.  *After this, the length-i prefixes of each string have equal widths.*